# Attempting to start git bisect gives 'fatal: invalid reference:...'

Tags: git, git-bisect

Attempting to start a bisect with the following command,

```
git bisect start
```

causes Git to respond:

```
fatal: invalid reference: atrium-3018
```

What is the cause of this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 14):

Apparent this is due to relics of a pevious bisect, that you can resolve with a simple:

```
rm .git/BISECT_*
```

(Thanks to [Christian](http://nerdbynature.de/s9y/?243) for the tip)

Edit - I haven't tested this - but it seems from the doco the more correct response maybe

```
git bisect reset
```

If anyone else hit this they may want to try the proper approach and report the outcome)

Comment: I've just had the same issue when trying to cancel an old bisect using the `git bisect reset` command you mentioned. Your suggestion about removing the temporary files fixed it for me :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, I got this error because of a months-old `git bisect` session. The branch which it had started had long been deleted.

My solution was to do

```
git bisect reset <branch name>
```

where `<branch name>` was a branch that actually exists in my local repo.

Alternatively, I imagine you can just create a new branch with the same name as the one `git bisect reset` is complaining about.